# How to show values in graph only between two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table containing the columns:

```
Name
Capacity per month
From date 
To Date
```

a couple of records could be:

> Person #1, 150, 01.01.2019, 01.07.19
>
> Person #2, 150, 01.02.2019, 01.05.19

So there are two persons with a capacity of 150 per month between the dates in each record.

I would like to summarize the capacity per month on a graph based on the from and to dates. My x-axis has dates and for january 2019 the total capacity should be 150, for february it should be 300.

How can I acheive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have a Calendar table, you can use this measure:

```
Monthly Capacity = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( Table1[Capacity] ),
    FILTER ( 
        Table1,
        Table1[From Date] <= ENDOFMONTH ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) && 
        Table1[To Date] >= STARTOFMONTH ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    )
)
```

Here's a worked example: https://excel.solutions/so_54687085/